# Accessing an image from another project using a relative path

Tags: c#, .net, path

In my solution i have two projects, "Project1" and "Project2". Please note that i am using VS 2010 and these projects are class library projects.

In "Project1" i have a "Resources" folder which contains an image file "MyPicture.png" .

So i am having this structure:

> - -MySolution
>
>   - Project1
>
>     - Resources
>
>       - MyPicture.png
>   - Project2

Now i need to reuse the same picture in "Project2". How can i access it ?

I tried this in "Project2" using relative paths something like:

> Image myImage = Image.FromFile(@"../Project1/Resources/MyPicture.png");

but i got a FileNotFoundException, also i tried different forms for the relative path but without success.

Could this image from "Project1" be accessed in Project2 by using just a relative path ? Or i need to use reflection and load the Project1 assembly in "Project2" and then access the picture, or is there another way to access that picture ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you use a resource (resx) file in Project1 to contain your image resources, and expose it publicly?

Comment: I can add a resources file in Project1 but i need to keep it marked as internal, this is a requirement.

Comment: See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396226/c-sharp-loading-image-from-file-resource-in-different-assembly

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i do not use WPF, i am just having some class library projects, and doing things in projects build events seems somehow complicated since i am not configuring the build of the projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, If are library projects you can use the ConfigurationManager, because they are dll.

example, use this code for get the path of the image on the config:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameConfig"]
```

and in the application config that use this .dll include the key with the path

example:

```
<add key="NameConfig" value="C:\MyFolder\MyImage.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i did not understood all what you wanted to say, but one thing that i noticed is that the "value C:\MyFolder\MyImage.jpg" is hardcoded and absolute so for instance if some other developer has the project lets say mapped from source control to D: partition instead of C: his build will not load the image because the path is wrong. To have this thing working i believe that only the paths relative to projects inside the solution has to be used.

Comment: The <add key="NameConfig" value="C:\MyFolder\MyImage.jpg"> is in the config, no hardcode. I think for your case the best solution is to load resources from the configuration of the application that use your class library, as you will share resources.